# Can't create animation in libgdx

Tags: animation, graphics, libgdx, game-engine

I'm trying to create animation but keep getting errors

```
package com.leopikinc.bobdestroyer;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;

public class MainMenu implements Screen{

    Texture background_main;
    TextureRegion[] background_textures;
    Animation background_animation;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    TextureRegion current_frame; 
    float stateTime;
    BobDestroyer game;

    public MainMenu(BobDestroyer game){
       this.game = game;
}

    @Override
    public void show() {
        background_main = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("main_menu_screen/Background.png"));
        //TextureRegion[][] temp = new TextureRegion.split(background_main, 128, 72);
        //background_textures = new TextureRegion[3];
        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            background_textures[i] = new TextureRegion(background_main,0, 0+72*i, 128, 72+72*i);
        }
        background_animation = new Animation(0.2f,background_textures);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
    //  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); 
        current_frame = background_animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
        batch.begin();
            batch.draw(current_frame, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

}
```

this is my code and then i try to launch it i get

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.leopikinc.bobdestroyer.MainMenu.show(MainMenu.java:31)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
>       at com.leopikinc.bobdestroyer.BobDestroyer.create(BobDestroyer.java:11)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)

How to fix this? And also when i use `TextureRegion[][] temp = new TextureRegion.split(background_main, 128, 72);`Eclipse says

> TextureRegion.split cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: You commented out the line where you instantiated your TextureRegion array so it's null. Regarding your second question, you need to remove the word new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TextureRegion.split cannot be resolved to a type

You are getting an error because you are using keyword `new`

Do something like this and your error will be fixed

```
 TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(background_main, background_main.getWidth()/TOTAL_COLS, background_main.getHeight()/TOTAL_ROWS);
```

Your second error is because you have commented the line where you are initializing your array, you need to uncomment this

```
//background_textures = new TextureRegion[3];
```